# Cloud Storage/Remote Storage - Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: windows-7, cloud, server-message-block, share, thin-client

Currently I am running "Windows 7 Embedded" on a few Thin Clients (HP T5570E). I would like to store all user files running on the clients on a remote server (Not local). I have attempted using "Folder Redirection" to a remote SMB share, this is very slow. Is there an easy solution to hosting all user files/folders (Profile) online to the cloud or a remote server. I have looked into running a remote Network file system on a server and having data saved to the network drive mounted in explorer but that does not solve the issue of having all files and documents stored remotely (Documents/Desktop/Downloads).

Can someone please suggest a solution. :)

Currently I am running a remote Server 2008 windows box.

Comment: Ok I'm going to attempt to use Xtreemfs to map a remote network location as a new drive then change the path for documents, downloads, desktop etc in the User Shell reg key. Ill see how I go.